# How to convert from Tensorflow.js (.json) model into Tensorflow (SavedModel) or Tensorflow Lite (.tflite) model?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensorflow.js, tensorflow2

I have [downloaded](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/posenet/mobilenet/float/050/model-stride16.json) a pre-trained PoseNet model for Tensorflow.js (tfjs) from Google, so its a **json** file.

However, I want to use it on Android, so I need the `.tflite` model. Although someone has 'ported' a similar model from tfjs to tflite [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55136861/how-to-use-outputs-of-posenet-model-in-tflite), I have no idea what model (there are many variants of PoseNet) they converted. I want to do the steps myself. Also, I don't want to run some arbitrary code someone uploaded into a file in stackOverflow:

> Caution: Be careful with untrusted code—TensorFlow models are code. See Using TensorFlow Securely for details. [Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)

Does anyone know any convenient ways to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find out what tfjs format you have by looking in the json file. It often says "graph-model". The difference between them are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829043/difference-between-tfjs-layers-model-and-tfjs-graph-model/63621486#63621486).

### From tfjs graph model to SavedModel (more common)

Use [tfjs-to-tf](https://github.com/patlevin/tfjs-to-tf/) by [Patrick Levin](https://github.com/patlevin).

```py
import tfjs_graph_converter.api as tfjs
tfjs.graph_model_to_saved_model(
               "savedmodel/posenet/mobilenet/float/050/model-stride16.json",
               "realsavedmodel"
            )

# Code below taken from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model("realsavedmodel")
tflite_model = converter.convert()

# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

---

### From tfjs layers model to SavedModel

**Note:** This will only work for layers model format, not graph model format as in the question. I've written the difference between them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829043/difference-between-tfjs-layers-model-and-tfjs-graph-model/63621486#63621486).

---

1. [Install](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-tensorflow-savedmodel-tensorflow-hub-module-keras-hdf5-or-tfkeras-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format) and use tensorflowjs-convert to convert the `.json` file into a Keras HDF5 file (from another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242701/how-to-convert-tensorflow-js-model-and-weights-to-standard-tensorflow)).

On mac, you'll face issues running pyenv ([fix](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/544#issuecomment-543089550)) and on Z-shell, pyenv won't load correctly ([fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59097786/pyenv-does-not-change-python-version-on-mac)). Also, once pyenv is running, use `python -m pip install tensorflowjs` instead of `pip install tensorflowjs`, because pyenv did not change python used by pip for me.

Once you've followed the [tensorflowjs_converter guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter#step-1-converting-a-tensorflow-savedmodel-tensorflow-hub-module-keras-hdf5-or-tfkeras-savedmodel-to-a-web-friendly-format), run `tensorflowjs_converter` to verify it works with no errors, and should just warn you about `Missing input_path argument`. Then:

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tfjs_layers_model --output_format=keras tfjs_model.json hdf5_keras_model.hdf5
```

2. Convert the Keras HDF5 file into a SavedModel (standard Tensorflow model file) or directly into `.tflite` file using the [TFLiteConverter](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api). The following runs in a Python file:

```
# Convert the model.
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('hdf5_keras_model.hdf5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert() 
    
# Save the TF Lite model.
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
f.write(tflite_model)
```

or to save to a SavedModel:

```
# Convert the model.
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('hdf5_keras_model.hdf5')
tf.keras.models.save_model(
    model, filepath, overwrite=True, include_optimizer=True, save_format=None,
    signatures=None, options=None
)
```

Comment: In step 1, the `tensorflowjs_converter` fails to convert [the PoseNet model](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/posenet/mobilenet/float/050/model-stride16.json). This GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1754) implies that the format of PoseNet models (such as the one referenced by the OP) is `tfjs_graph_model` (not `tf_layers_model`) which cannot be converted to Keras. How did you manage to convert the PoseNet model to Keras?

Comment: Steps to reproduce: run Docker container `python:3.8`, then install TensorFlow.js `pip install tensorflowjs`, then try to convert `tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tfjs_layers_model --output_format=keras /posenet/js/model-stride16.json /posenet/keras/hdf5_keras_model.hdf5`. Error message: `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 101, in deserialize
    layer_class_name = config['class_name']
KeyError: 'class_name'`

Comment: Apologies Glen, I didn't know about the distinction between graph model and layers model formats. I was the OP, and basically did not answer my own question. My answer will only work for `tfjs_layers_model`

Comment: No worries. Meanwhile, I found a solution in [TensorFlow.js Graph Model Converter](https://github.com/patlevin/tfjs-to-tf) which can reliably convert TensorFlow.js graph model to SavedModel format. From there, it should be quite straightforward to get TF Lite model, if needed.

Comment: Thanks @Glen, I've been able to create a model.tflite as well, and have updated the answer for both graph and layers model formats.

Comment: @BenButterworth I am able to convert the posenet resnet50 tf.js model[https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/posenet/resnet50/float/model-stride16.json] into tflite model using your method. But generated tflite model accepts the input details with 'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int32)

Comment: @BenButterworth Nice answer. +1. Is there any way to do this for TF 1.X models?

Comment: Thanks :), I highly recommend avoiding trying to convert models that have touched TensorFlow 1.x, it seems like it should be possible but vaguely, it has always led to a lot of issues for me in the past.