# Converting teachable machine model into tflite format

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow.js, tensorflow-lite

So I have trained a posenet model for classifying different poses on the teachable machine learning website ([link for the website](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/)). I want to use this trained model in a flutter app, and for that I need to convert the model into tflite format. I checked many online blogs which said that the website has an option of converting it to that format, but they have removed that feature. Thus, I wanted to know how can I convert this teachable machine model into tflite format?

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded a pose model of my own from that site, and the zip appears to be a Tensorflow.JS model.

[image: contents of the Teachable Machine Learning model]

[image: metadata.json contents]

Now that we know the unzipped file is just a TF.js model, refer to a tutorial like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544836/how-to-convert-from-tensorflow-js-json-model-into-tensorflow-savedmodel-or) to convert the TFJS model back into a keras SavedModel, which can be then saved into a tflite model.

Comment: so I followed your steps and converted my model to tflite format. But when I try to implement it in the flutter app, some error "ArrayIndex out of bounds exception" comes. I wonder if its the issue of conversion